# How to convert XSSFWorkbook to File

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I currently have an `XSSFWorkbook` and would like to cast it or somehow change it to `File` within the Java code. Is there any way of doing so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [XSSFWorkbook.write(java.io.OutputStream stream)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) to write the content to a file.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("yourFileName.xls");
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
//do your stuff ...

wb.write(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bellow code is used and tested.

```
private Response sendExcelFile(Locale locale, Optional<List<List<String>>> consumersReportData) {
    XSSFWorkbook workBook = ExportToExcelUtils.prepareWorkBook(consumersReportData.get(), "data");



    String DisplayFileName = "Consumers-Report-" + DateUtils.getLocalDateInString(DateUtils.now());
    String fileName = "/tmp/fileName.xlsx";

// Created file object here 

    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        workBook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.error("File not found : fileName {}  Exception details:{} ", fileName, e);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IO exception  : fileName {}  Exception details:{} ", fileName, e);

    }

    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok((Object) file);
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DisplayFileName + EXCEL_FILE_EXTENSTION);
    return responseBuilder.build();
}
```